# How to set max-height of an image to height of the parent div in CSS rules?

Tags: html, css, image, height

I need the height of an image to be constrained to the parent's div height containing text. Is there a way to do this in CSS?

I have the following:

```css
img {
  float: right;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/e51/tokyo05-2-1447803.jpg" />
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute positioning is one of the solutions

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 100%;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the image as background

```css
.box {
  background:url("https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/e51/tokyo05-2-1447803.jpg") right/auto 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```